# How can I add the contents of different files into one file?

Tags: python, new-operator

I'm very new to python and this is far beyond what I'm capable of.

I have multiple text files:
test01.txt
test02.txt
test03.txt
test*.txt

Each file has same number of lines, and the same structure.

I want to extract lines 20-25 and put that into a text file that I can manipulate in excel.

Because there are hundreds of files, it would be great if we could put the text file name on top or next to the data.

This is what I was able to do, but as you can see it's not exactly "fast":

```py
file1 = open("test01.txt", "r")

content = file1.readlines()

file1 = open("values.txt","w")

file1.write("test01.txt" + "\n")

file1.writelines(content[33:36])

file1.close()

file1 = open("test02.txt", "r")

content = file1.readlines()

#Append-adds at last

file1 = open("values.txt","a")#append mode

file1.write("test02.txt" + "\n")

file1.writelines(content[33:36])

file1.close()

file1 = open("test03.txt", "r")

content = file1.readlines()

#Append-adds at last

file1 = open("values.txt","a")#append mode

file1.write("test03.txt" + "\n")

file1.writelines(content[33:36])

file1.close()
```

Comment: This is a pretty good project for a new programmer to take on. It plays to the strength of python. You are showing some skills since are familiar with file manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script where you can read all files in a directory and write the name of the file and the content into a another file like you did.

```
import os

ValuesTextFile = open("values.txt","a")
Path = './files/'
for Filename in os.listdir(Path):
   print (Filename)
   ValuesTextFile.writelines(Filename)
   File = open(Path + Filename, "r")
   Content = File.readlines()
   ValuesTextFile.writelines(Content[33:36])
   File.close()
ValuesTextFile.close()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. It works as expected.